# Flip Fragment to Another Fragment inside ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` that contains 4 fragments (`fragment1`, `fragment2`, `fragment3`, `fragment4`). I populate the `ViewPager`  with a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` on `getItem()`. On `fragment3` I want to be able to click a button  and flip to another fragment (otherFragment).  I want to be able to have the ability to swipe the `ViewPager` or hit the back button and return to the last viewed fragment (fragment3 or otherfragment).  I have a minimum sdk of api 8.Can some one point me in the right direction to accomplish this?

```
 @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return Fragment1.newInstance();
            case 1:
                return Fragment2.newInstance();
            case 2:
                return Fragment3.newInstance();
            case 3:
                return Fragment4.newInstance();

            default:
                return Fragment1.newInstance();
        }
    }
```

Comment: yeah..when you click on each fragment in view pager..enters into another fragment and when you click on back you have to come to same fragment na...is this you are asking..?

Comment: @GVSharma  I want to show "otherFragment" (like the other side of a card) when I click on a button on "fragment3" that is in the viewPager.  This new "otherFragment" is not accessible through swiping, only through clicking the button on "fragment3".

Comment: yeah ...we can do this...and moreover your approach towards this is right..